# meaning of ''bearing gifts'' in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does **''bearing gifts''** mean?
forexample, you are going to travel to a county, your friends might tell you, take some some **bearing gifts** for your host.

Comment: Thanks. but what does that mean carrying gift itself?what kind of gift is that?

Comment: "Take some bearing gifts" does not sound like standard English to me.

Comment: I know. but I mean what sort of gift is a carrying gift?

Comment: You would not *take some bearing gifts*.  You would *bear gifts*. This is not some special kind of gifts.  This is a description of what you are doing with the gifts.  Look up the verb "bear" and see if you can find a meaning that fits this.

Comment: The idiom is biblical.  The Three Wise Men visited the baby Jesus "bearing gifts" of gold, frankincense, and myrrh.

Comment: I reckon ''bearing'' plays its role as an adjective here.

Comment: @user403900 - "Bearing" means "carrying".

Comment: Possibly a typo, you can *come* bearing gifts. What would you bring a host when you visit for dinner? Wine, flowers, chocolate, or the equivalent?

Comment: @GEdgar - I might take some bearing gifts if I was visiting a friend who is an amateur auto mechanic.

Answer (score 2):

"Bearing gifts" are not special kinds of gifts. "Bearing" is the gerund form of the verb "to bear" meaning to carry.

So

> He is bearing gifts

Means that he is carrying gifts. The term is most associated with the saying "Beware of Greeks bearing gifts" which derives from Homer's telling of the ancient Greek-Trojan war, where the Greeks pretended to seek peace and presented a giant wooden horse as a gift, but in reality concealed their soldiers inside it. So it means "be careful of your enemies when they bring gifts to you ".

"Take some bearing gifts" is incorrect English, so if your friend said that we cannot tell you what they meant.

Comment: so much obliged.

Comment: If your host is car or motorbike enthusiast in a country with poor access to spare parts, some bearings _as_ gifts might be very acceptable, :-)

Answer (score 0):

“ bring some bearing gifts “ means either a compass or hollow discs to help your wheel spin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Or 'bring some people who are carrying gifts'. But the question itself doesn't belong on a site aimed at proficient linguists.